# Symfony2 - doctrine:schema:create Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, localhost

**/app/config/parameters.ini**

```
[parameters]
    database_driver   = pdo_mysql
    database_host     = localhost
    database_port     =
    database_name     = my_dbname
    database_user     = my_user
    database_password = my_password
```

**Linux shell**

```
/var/www/Symfony$ mysql -u my_user -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| my_dbname          |
| test               |
+--------------------+

mysql> Bye
/var/www/Symfony$ php app/console doctrine:schema:create

[PDOException]                                                               
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using pa  
ssword: YES)
```

What can be possible cause(s) of the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My password was containing a `@` character which was posing the problem.

Comment: I generally create a dedicated user for each table. In phpMyAdmin you have an option for that, when you want to add a new user, tick: _Create database with same name and grant all privileges_ ->  http://i.stack.imgur.com/7SbDU.png

Comment: You mean a dedicated user for each __database__. That's what I did (this is a good practice) I don't use phpMyAdmin. My user creation query should be ok, I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: @JavierIEH Certain caracters may be problematic in passwords, check your password. That was my problem